# Скрипт крашится на строчке logger.add('logs.log)

Tags: python, логирование

Всем привет, есть написанный скрипт, при запуске двойным щелчком мыши скрипт не запускается. Черный экран на секунду и все. Текста там никакого нет вообще. Поэкспериментировал через принты и инпуты и понял, что крашится именно на строчке: `logger.add('logs.log')`, она у меня идет сразу после всех импортов. Логгер - `loguru` (`from loguru import logger`). Библиотека установлена через `pip install`, все ок. В `Pycharm` работает, если запускать скрипт через `cmd` - то все также работает прекрасно, включая логгер. Но вот если двойным щелчком через `Python` - такая беда. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема? Не знаю, где искать, у меня не так много опыта. Буду очень признателен за любую помощь!
Windows 11 x64
Python 3.10.10

UPD: Благодарю @CrazyElf за помощь!

Указание путя полностью решило проблему, теперь все работает как надо и ничего не крашится logger.add('C:\Users\User\Desktop\Python\logs.log')

Comment: Видимо, при таком запуске текущий каталог у скрипта получается такой, в который у него нет прав писать и при попытки записи в этот каталог файла `logs.log` скрипт крашится. Ну либо у вас питон вообще не запускается, сложно вот так понять.

Comment: @CrazyElf , Благодарю за то, что откликнулись! Без логгера скрипт работает корректно в Python двойным щелчком, то есть с Python все ок. По поводу первого, что вы сказали - у вас нету случайно рекомендаций, как это можно пофиксить?

Comment: Для начала можете попробовать указать полный путь для лог-файла )  Ну или сделать ярлык для запуска файла, и прописать там рабочий каталог. Я просто так и не очень понял, как вы запускаете. В принципе, в питоне можно получить каталог, в котором лежит запущенный скрипт (это не то же, что рабочий каталог). И писать файл в этот каталог. Можно по-разному сделать.

Comment: @CrazyElf указание полного путя для лог-файла полностью решило проблему)) Спасибо большое)) Надеюсь, этот вопрос поможет кому-то)

Comment: Только бэкслэши нужно либо экранировать и для этого писать двойные бэкслэши `logger.add('C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\Python\\logs.log')`, либо ещё лучше использовать r-строки: `logger.add(r'C:\Users\User\Desktop\Python\logs.log')`.